# How to check clickable checkbox with Espresso?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I have clickable checkbox in my application, it looks like this:

[image: Img]

If user taps on "Terms and Conditions" then web browser will be opened.

I am writing Espresso test and `onView(withId(R.id.myCheckbox)).perform(click())` actually opens web browser instead of checking checkbox - as I would click "Terms and Conditions" . Is there any possibility to check that checkbox with Espresso without modyfing my code? This checkbox must remain clickable.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening if your IDs and layout are correct. Are you able to work with the dev team or dig into the layout yourself? I've seen some very "hacky" methods to hyperlink text on Android before, which may be causing what you're seeing.

Could you perhaps provide some screenshots from Layout Inspector?

Comment: We are setting this hyperlink through code by adding onClickListener on this view. So I think that opening browser is proper behaviour of application when we click on that hyperlink. Now im looking for other solution for checking this checkbox. I thought about clicking on specific coordinates but they would be different for different devices

Comment: Definitely don’t click coordinates. I’d dig deeper with someone more familiar with the app code.